# Ruby on Rails - arquivo .html.erb não atualiza no servidor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Modifiquei o arquivo show.html.erb, mas as alterações não são exibidas no sistema, comecei a mexer ha pouco tempo com ruby no redmine, poderia ser cache ou é necessária alguma compilação no arquivo modificado?

Comment: não é preciso nenhum compilação desde que você não esteja rodando a sua aplicação em production mode

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi obrigado pela resposta, o sistema esta em produção, o que devo fazer?

Comment: mudar para o rails development. Não sei como faz isso no redmine pq não uso a IDE.

Comment: Olá, pode mandar um print do que está sendo renderizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se voce estiver rodando a sua aplicação no servidor entao toda vez que voce fizer uma mudança será necessário reiniciar o servidor rails para que as mudanças sejam atualizadas.

Se a sua aplicação estiver localmente recomendo subir o servidor em modo 'developmemt'